# building a telerik treeview clientside works but doesnt expand showing children

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a Treeview.  This treeview gets populated client side with children in javascript using something along the lines of:

```
treeView.trackChanges();
var newNode = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNode();
newNode.set_text(node);
hasParent.get_nodes().add(newNode);
treeView.commitChanges();
```

The downside is that when looking at the client, the tree doesnt expand, to show these children.  Am i missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isnt here with the expanding, but more so on the Underlying Telerik Control.  To get around this, you need to set the onClientNodeExpanded = "FUNCTION_CALL" as in this expample, it was doing onClientNodeExpanding.  Also in this example, I did not assign a value.  In my final answer, i did.